# Is there a way to get public tweets of a user without using the Twitter Developer API?

Tags: twitter, scrapely

I applied for a Twitter Developer account 48 hours ago and it is not approved yet.

So, Is there some other way to get public tweets of a user?

Comment: Using the API is the only correct way to do this. The Twitter terms of service prohibit any other means of attempting to collect data from the platform. Please be patient as your developer account is reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

The embed widget provides a way to get a JSON representation of a user's timeline.

`https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/timeline/profile?screen_name=TwitterDev`

Now, there are some limitations. This doesn't give you a typical API response - you get HTML formatted data.  There are [some configuration options](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/guides/parameter-reference) but not many.